# Run tests from Clojure Repl and Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

As a newbie to clojure, I have used leiningen to create a sample project with

```
lein new app first-project
```

which gave me this directory

```
.
├── doc
│   └── intro.md
├── LICENSE
├── project.clj
├── README.md
├── resources
├── src
│   └── first_project
│       └── core.clj
├── target
│   └── repl
│       ├── classes
│       └── stale
│           └── extract-native.dependencies
└── test
    └── first_project
        └── core_test.clj
```

Without modifying any files, I can lauch successfully the only failing test with

```
lein test
...
Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
1 failures, 0 errors.
Tests failed.
```

But I am unable to do the same from the REPL using run-tests

```
lein repl
first-project.core=> (use 'clojure.test)
nil
first-project.core=> (run-tests)

Testing first-project.core

Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
{:type :summary, :pass 0, :test 0, :error 0, :fail 0}
```

I tried (but does not work)

```
(require 'first-project.core-test)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your example above the repl is in the wrong namespace. It may work better if you switch the repl to the `core_test` namespace. and then run `(run-tests)`.

```
(in-ns 'first-project.core-test)
(run-tests)
```

Another fun way of developing tests is to just run them from the REPL until they work, because tests are normal functions with some extra metadata.

```
(in-ns 'first-project.core-test)
(my-test)
```

Remember you have to load the file in addition to calling `in-ns`  Let's say your test file is `tests/first_project/core_test.clj`, then you will need to call

```
(load "tests/first_project/core_test")
(in-ns 'first-project.core-test)
(my-test)
```

Keep in mind that `_` in the file system becomes `-` in the namespace and `/` becomes `.`.

Comment: After (in-ns 'first-project.core-test), the repl does not know anymore the namespaces for run-tests or require/use functions. I tried (clojure.test/run-tests) but it did not find any tests (Ran 0 tests)

Comment: load the file first. In emacs this is ctrl-c ctrl-k

Comment: you can also switch the repl to the namespace with ctrl-c alt-n

Comment: This doesn't work (running Clojure 1.10). No tests are found. The [`require`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require) way of doing it works. This is because [`in-ns`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/in-ns) just sets the "current namespace" for the Clojure runtime but doesn't load anything from class files or wherever to actually fill that namespace.

Answer (score 70):

Start a REPL with `lein repl`, then use [require](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require)

```
(require '[clojure.test :refer [run-tests]])
(require 'your-ns.example-test :reload-all)
(run-tests 'your-ns.example-test)
```

I prefer to stay in the `user` namespace, as opposed to changing it with `in-ns` as mentioned by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21294710/109618). Instead, pass the namespace as an argument to `run-tests` (as shown above).

I'd also recommend staying away from `(use 'clojure.test)`; that is why I suggested `(require '[clojure.test :refer [run-tests]])` above. For more background, read http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-879

Comment: Worth adding `:refresh-all` to `require 'your-ns`

Comment: @JakubM indeed, but it needs to be `:reload-all`: `(require 'incanter.core-tests :reload-all)`

Answer (score 1):

To recap:

Way of [`require`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/require)

Full qualification of functions is only needed if you issued an `in-ns` earlier. Then do:

```
(clojure.core/require '[clojure.core :refer [require]]
                      '[clojure.test :refer [run-tests]]
                      '[clojure.repl :refer [dir]])
```

---

```
; Load whatever is in namespace "foo.bar-test" and reload everything
; if `:reload-all` has been additionally given

(require 'foo.bar-test :reload-all) 
;=> nil

; List your tests for good measure (Note: don't quote the namespace symbol!)

(dir foo.bar-test)
;=> t-math
;=> t-arith
;=> t-exponential
;=> nil 

; Check meta-information on a test to verify selector for example 

(meta #'foo.bar-test/t-math)
;=> {:basic-math true, :test #object[foo.bar_tes...

; `run-tests` will probably run nothing because the current namespace
; doesn't contain any tests, unless you have changed it with "in-ns"

(run-tests) 
;=> Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.

; run tests by giving namespace explicitly instead

(run-tests 'foo.bar-test) 
;=> Ran 3 tests containing 29 assertions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that if you are using VsCode + Calva, you can run the repl and run Tests for Current Namespace  `ctrl+alt+c t`