# Run one Clojure test (not all tests in a namespace), with fixtures, from the REPL

Tags: testing, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

How do I run one test (not a whole namespace) from the Clojure REPL?

I've tried calling the function directly, e.g. `(the-ns/the-test)` but I need fixtures to run first. So I want to find a way to start the tests from `clojure.test`.

This is close but not a match for what I want to do:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337705/109618

I don't see any mention of how to do it from the [clojure.test API](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There was a new function added in Clojure 1.6 to support this. [clojure.test/test-vars](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/test-vars) will run one or more test vars with fixtures.

I think something like this should work:

```
(clojure.test/test-vars [#'the-ns/the-test])
```

Comment: Then file a bug at https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ with a reproducible test.

Answer (score 5):

To run a single test in a namespace:

```
lein test :only namespace_name/testname
```

To run a all tests in one namespace

```
lein test :only namespace_name
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind not running fixtures, you could do the following before you call `run-tests`:

```
(defn test-ns-hook []
  (my-test))
```

To remove the hook, you can do

```
(ns-unmap *ns* 'test-ns-hook)
```

If you still need your fixtures and want to stay with one test namespace, you could add an `ns-unmap` to remove all the tests/fixtures you don't want to run from the namespace before running your tests modelled on something like:

```
(doseq [v (keys (ns-publics 'my-ns))]
  (let [vs (str v)]
    (if (.startsWith vs "test-") (ns-unmap 'my-ns v))))
```

It might be easier to work with multiple namespaces, one of which contains all your tests and fixtures and in other namespace(s) `refer` to the tests and fixtures you want to run from you main test namespace. You could then use `ns` to switch to a specific test namespace or pass `run-tests` the namespace(s) you want to test:

```
(ns test-main
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(deftest addition
  (is (= 4 (+ 2 2)))
  (is (= 7 (+ 3 4))))

(deftest subtraction
  (is (= 1 (- 4 3)))
  (is (= 3 (- 7 4))))

(run-tests)
;Runs all the tests

(ns test-specific
(:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
          [test-main :refer :all]))

(deftest arithmetic
  (subtraction))

(run-tests)
;Just runs the tests you want
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice alternative to clojure.test (if you're OK adding additional dependencies is `eftest`). This library is an alternative runner (it is compatible with clojure.test). It has flexible tests selectors (i.e. by folder, by namespace, by var).

In a REPL, you're able to execute something like this:

`(require '[eftest.runner :refer [find-tests run-tests]])
(run-tests (find-tests #'foo.bar/baz))`

See https://github.com/weavejester/eftest