# Clojure.test and Leinigen: How to run just a single test from command line

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojure.test

this:

[Run one Clojure test (not all tests in a namespace), with fixtures, from the REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970853/run-one-clojure-test-not-all-tests-in-a-namespace-with-fixtures-from-the-rep)

works fine with repl, how can I do this from command line using Leinigen?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably:

```
lein test :only my.namespace/my-test
```

Note that:

```
lein help test
```

outputs:

```
"A default :only test-selector is available to run select tests. For example,
`lein test :only leiningen.test.test/test-default-selector` only runs the
specified test. A default :all test-selector is available to run all tests."
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I just changed the answer a little so I can accept it.